# how to add all values of JSONObject to JSONArray

Tags: android

First, I want to add all `ArrayList` Values into `JsonObject` then I want to add these JSON object to `JsonArray` I have done wright in the first I have added all `ArrayList` to `JsonObject` but I can't add all `JsonObject` to `JsonArray`.

This is my code to convert json object to json Array:-

```
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

            for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("sid", records.get(i).getsid());
                    jsonObject.put("name", records.get(i).getpName());


                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject));





                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.e("ATTENDANCE", jsonArray.toString() + "");
        }

    });
```

I am getting only the last value of the ArrayList please help me I want The output to be like these

```
  [
        {
              "student_no":"3924/08",
              "firstname":"olana
        },
        {
              "student_no":"4011/08",
              "firstname":"yallem"
        }
  ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because you're creating only one object and putting it inside the for loop and you have to create new objects for every iteration.

Put your

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
```

inside your for loop

like this

```
        for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                jsonObject.put("sid", records.get(i).getsid());
                jsonObject.put("name", records.get(i).getpName());
                jsonArray.put(jsonObject));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: very helpful it works like charm...thank you for your fast response

Comment: @OlanaKenea Glad i could help. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                    jsonObject.put("sid", records.get(i).getsid());
                    jsonObject.put("name", records.get(i).getpName());
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.e("ATTENDANCE", jsonArray.toString() + "");
        }

    });
```

Comment: whats the difference between your answer and the answer below?